# Name of the Statements with Heuristic?

Tags: logic

I am somewhat confused the categories of theorem, proposition and heuristics.
Assume that I make a proposition, called X, with (already known) heuristic assumptions.
That is, the statement X is: under several heuristics, something holds under some conditions.

In computer science, the statement is usually called a 'theorem'. However, as I know, in the mathematics, any `theorems' do not allow any heuristic assumptions.
In this situation, how we can call the X? Can I call it 'theorem' or 'proposition' or other names?
What is the formal name of X which consists of several heuristic statements?

Comment: A short answer to "what do you call a statement made with heuristic assumptions" might be "a heuristic". Can you give a concrete example of such a "theorem" in computer science?

Comment: @davidlowryduda I found this paper http://imperia.rz.rub.de:8032/imperia/md/content/may/paper/ac08_divisor.pdf. Theorem 3 used a heuristic assumption.

Comment: It seems like they call their statements made with this assumption as "heuristic", such as a "heuristic algorithm". It's common in all branches of computation to have heuristics. See for example [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3149) for very "mathy" examples.

Comment: @davidlowryduda Thanks!